# Nodejs Async Promise Queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, queue, es6-promise

I need to consume a rate limited API. For example, I can only make 10 API calls in a second, so I will need to wait the end of the current second to make another API call.

To achieve this, I want to make an asynchronous queue that can manage this on its own. The main functionality of it is to let me add a new promise to the queue, and when the promise is resolved the application is notified:

```
let queue = new Queue()

queue.add(api.get('/somepath')).then(res => { // handle response });
```

How can I implement this using ordinary Promises?

```
export class AsyncQueue {

    private queue: Array<Promise<any>>;


    add(promise, fct) {
        this.queue.push(promise);
    }

    resolveNext() {
        this.queue.pop().then({
            // how to resolve the waiting promise in my application
        })
    }

    get length() {
        return this.queue.length
    }

}
```

Comment: That sounds like a job for Observables.

Comment: i think it can be done using only promise?

Comment: Looking at your code it looks like `api.get()` will be called immediately. Shouldn't get be called after it's been `pop()`ed from the queue?

Comment: Why don't you chain the response handling promise to the api call?

Comment: It *can* be done with a needle and a steady hand, but I generally prefer a battle-tested pubsub with a thriving community over my own adhoc implementation.

Comment: @JaredSmith i wanted something tha build on the top of an exisitng api and using promises

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the current implementation, `api.get()` will be called *immediately* when `add`ed to the queue. You should `add` the *path* instead (or maybe both `api.get` and the `path`) and have `AsyncQueue` initialize the Promise when it's able. Make sure to have `add` return a Promise that resolves once the API call is done.

For example, in vanilla JS, it could look like this:

```js
const apiGet = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

class AsyncQueue {
  queue = [];
  constructor() {
    setInterval(this.resolveNext.bind(this), 2000);
  }
  add(fn, param) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.queue.unshift({ fn, param, resolve });
    });
  }
  resolveNext() {
    if (!this.queue.length) return;
    const { fn, param, resolve } = this.queue.pop();
    fn(param).then(resolve);
  }
}


const queue = new AsyncQueue()
console.log('start');
// Will resolve after 2000 + 1000 seconds:
queue.add(apiGet, '/somepath').then(res => {
  console.log('handling response 1');
});
// Will resolve after 4000 + 1000 seconds:
queue.add(apiGet, '/somepath').then(res => {
  console.log('handling response 2');
});
```

Comment: That's a really nice way to do that.

Comment: There is so much time I wait to find a solution to my problem which is to call asynchronous function when the previous is completed, using a queue. The remaining problem is the stack, if asynchronous function needs more time that caller. But that is life.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid permanent call to resolveNext(), is it possible to implement like this ?

```
class AsyncQueue {
  
    /* delayBetween: delay (ms) before calling next item
        */
  constructor( delayBetween) {
        this.queue = [];
        this.id = 0;
        if (delayBetween < 1) {
            delayBetween = 1;
        }
        this.delayBetween = delayBetween;
        this.timer = null;
    // setInterval( this.resolveNext.bind(this), this.delayBetween);
  }
    
  add(fn, param) {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        // liste inversée : le dernier élément ajouté est au début du tableau
        this.id ++;
        param.queueId = this.id;
        // console.log( `${new Date().yyyymmddhhmmsslll()} > push request: ${JSON.stringify(param)}`);
      this.queue.unshift( { fn, param, resolve } );
        // console.log( `${new Date().yyyymmddhhmmsslll()} > add() > setTimeout...`);
        if (this.timer == null) {
            this.timer = setTimeout( this.resolveNext.bind(this), this.delayBetween);
        }
    });
  }
    
  resolveNext() {
        this.timer = null;
        // console.log( `${new Date().yyyymmddhhmmsslll()} > resolveNext() > called, len: ${this.queue.length}...`);
    if ( ! this.queue.length) return;       
    const { fn, param, resolve } = this.queue.pop();
        // console.log( `${new Date().yyyymmddhhmmsslll()} > pop request: ${JSON.stringify(param)}`);
        // execute fn, and call resolve only when finished
    // fn(param).then(resolve);
    fn(param).then((result) => {
        // console.log( `${new Date().yyyymmddhhmmsslll()} > fn resolved: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
        if (this.timer == null) {
            this.timer = setTimeout( this.resolveNext.bind(this), this.delayBetween);
        }
    });
  }
}
```